# Can you detect if a msg.sender is a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

If i have a function in solidity being called, is there a way that the function can know if the `msg.sender` is a smart contract?

Comment: Check out this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/check-if-msg-sender-is-a-specific-type-of-contract

Comment: You could just check if `msg.sender == tx.origin`. If false, the caller is smart contract.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can:

```
function isContract(address _address) returns (bool isContract){
  uint32 size;
  assembly {
    size := extcodesize(_address)
  }
  return (size > 0);//Warning: will return false if the call is made from the constructor of a smart contract
}
```

Comment: While the contract's constructor is executing, it has a code size of 0. (Perhaps this also happens after a `selfdestruct` call?) So if the question is about security in some fashion, just don't try to differentiate. But if it's for something like "If recipient is a contract, we want to first try to call this function," then a best-effort method like this could have a valid use case.

Comment: @user94559 That's a pretty important oversight, I've edited the original code to have a //note explaining that. Normally I wouldn't ever edit another user's code over a comment but given that smart contracts may be handling serious amounts of money I think it's really important that this doesn't get overlooked by someone copy-pasting this function.

Comment: Wouldn't combining this with a `msg.sender == tx.origin` check avoid a spoofed call from the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a safe way to detect if msg.sender is a smartcontract since this can be hacked by doing the calls from the constructor of a smart contract.

Etherenaut's 14th level "Gatekeeper Two" is about this issue. See explanation in:
[Ethernaut Lvl 14 Gatekeeper 2 Walkthrough: How contracts initialize (and how to do bitwise operations)](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethernaut-lvl-14-gatekeeper-2-walkthrough-how-contracts-initialize-and-how-to-do-bitwise-ddac8ad4f0fd)

> extcodesize(sender) should return 0, if extcodesize is a subroutine inside the sender contract’s original constructor function